# Operational error : Unable to use a closed cursor Openerp 7

Tags: database, postgresql, openerp-7

When trying to create a database from the user interface, it shows:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 168, in exp_create_database
    _initialize_db(self, id, db_name, demo, lang, user_password)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 98, in _initialize_db
    cr.close()
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 160, in wrapper
    raise psycopg2.OperationalError(msg) OperationalError: Unable to use a closed cursor.
```

The SQL connection is closed, but I don't know why.

### Potential solution 1:

After further researche, I found that to be able to create the database from the user interface, you should perform the following configuration:

In `openerp-server.conf`, you should put on `db_password`: the password for the role attributed to the `openerp` user. It's that role that gives the `openerp` user the ability to create databases from the user interface. If the two passwords do not match, you won't be able to create databases from the user interface.

In my case, I found that my `openerp-server.conf` contained:

```
db_password : False,
```

I changed it to the password of the role given to the `openerp` user (`createdb`), I restarted the server but nothing changed. When trying to create the database from the user interface, the same error occurs.

### Potential Solution 2:

I tried to create the database from psql by accessing postgres from the shell with the `openerp` user. I tried:

```
createdb db_name
```

The database is created, but I can't log in. I don't know how to attribute my database creation to an administrator account while performing `createdb`. The functional side of this potential solution is to be able to perform the same database creation process from the user interface as postgres.

Can anyone give me a hand with these two potential solutions? I'm really struggling with this.

Comment: Hi, Did you try using a db-filter to start the openerp server?

Comment: Hi, no, how can I do it ?